# Подскажите как сюда внедрить парсер погоды чтобы он выводил результат в поле с сообщением

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Есть код на php работающий с принятием отправкой запросов от ВК -https://vk.com. Подскажите как сюда внедрить парсер погоды чтобы он выводил результат в поле с сообщением.

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) { 
  return; 
} 

$confirmation_token = 'строка подтверждения'; 
$token = 'токен'; 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 

switch ($data->type) { 

  case 'confirmation':
    echo $confirmation_token; 
    break; 

  case 'message_new':
    $user_id = $data->object->user_id;
    $user_info = 
json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=
{$user_id}&v=5.0")); 
    $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name; 
    $message = $data->object->body;
    $messages_array = [
            'Погода Москва' => "поле с сообщением (ответ)"
    ];
    foreach($messages_array as $k => $v){
        if($message == $k){$otwet = $v;}
}
    $request_params = [
        'message' => $otwet,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'v' => '5.0'
];

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 

echo('ok'); 

break; 

}
```

Comment: спарсить погоду, и вставить в сообщение, в чем проблема то?

Comment: Использовать API прогнозов, допустим openweathermap. Там получить JSON, распарсить его и вставить в сообщение в необходимом формате вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим такой проект, который я использую у себя с помощью `OpenWeatherMap`. Остальную вставку в ваш код производите так, как вам нужно. Это конкретный модуль получения и обработки погоды. Токен вам необходимо получить отдельно на сайте.

```php
<?php

$weath_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Токен погоды

        $link = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Minsk&mode=json&units=metric&lang=ru&cnt=1&APPID='.$weath_token; //Прогноз на сегодня
        $weather = json_decode(file_get_contents($link)); //Получаем и декодим
        $gorod = $weather->city->name; //Получаем название города
        $country = $weather->city->country; //Страны
        $Days    = $weather->list; //Разбиваем сам прогноз
            foreach ($Days as $Day) {
                $date_unix       = date("d.m.Y", $Day->dt); //Дата
                $morn        = $Day->temp->morn; //Температура утром
                $day         = $Day->temp->day; //Температура днем
                $eve         = $Day->temp->eve; //Температура вечером
                $night       = $Day->temp->night; //Температура ночью
                $pressure    = $Day->pressure; //Давление
                $humidity    = $Day->humidity; //Влажность
                $pressure    = $pressure / 1.333333333333; //Перевод давления из Паскалей в мм ртутного столба
                $pressure    = round($pressure, 2); //округляем давление
                $dayweather = "Утром: {$morn} °C<br>Днем: {$day} °C<br>Вечером: {$eve} °C<br>Ночью: {$night} °C<br>Давление: {$pressure} мм рт.ст.<br>Влажность: {$humidity} %<br><br>"; //Собираем все в красивое сообщение
            }

        $otwet =  "Прогноз на {$date_unix}<br><br>{$gorod},{$country}<br>{$dayweather}"; // Отправляем ответ
```